# I have to pull down list item element without moving down its background image (blue border)

Tags: html, css

[image]

I have problem in my navbar side borders. In the list item of navbar I have used the background image for border (the blue line). Is there any way so I can pull down my two list items little below as you can see in my screenshot. I have to pull down both this list "**become a voice over**" and "**message**" a little down.

If I use `margin` or `position` both doesn't work for me because border is background image of these list items.
So when I pull down background image border list items moves down too.

Comment: please post your problematic codes with your question

Comment: We need your code or we can't help you :)

Comment: It can be adjusted in many ways. but we need code. can you post your code in a  fiddle ..https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking into `box-sizing: border-box`. If you remove that property from `.li, .lastItem` in the the snippet below you run into the issue you were describing.

It is hard to know for sure since you haven't posted your code. If this isn't the problem you are seeing, please update the snippet (or use jsfiddle) so we can help you further.

```css
.navbar { 
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul, li, div {
  display: block;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 40px;
}

ul {
  float: left;
}

li, .lastItem {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: red solid 1px;
}

li {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 9px;
  border: red solid 1px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.lastItem {
  padding-top: 4px;
  float: right;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>World</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="lastItem">What a fine day</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't add image until i get 10 reputations?